# Some problems about the pointer

Tags: objective-c

It is a basic question which really confuses me a lot: what is the difference between the condition when * is inside the ( ) and the condition * is used without ()? In other words, what is the difference between `int *myPointer` and `(NSString *)description`?

Comment: You may want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the form without brackets:

```
NSString *name;
```

is how you declare a variable to be a pointer to a certain type of object. In objective C, you deal with and pass around pointers to Objective C objects,  not actual objects. (If you try to declare `NSString name`, i.e. not a pointer, the compiler will throw up an error.)

Something of the format `(NSString *)description` can occur in two different contexts.

The first form:

```
- (int)doSomethingToString:(NSString *)str {
```

is describing the type of a parameter to a method. In other words, `str` is a pointer to an `NSString`.

The second form:

```
// suppose myArray be an array of NSString objects...
int firstStringLength = [(NSString *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0] length];
```

is used to tell the compiler that an object has a certain type. In the above example, we are giving the compiler the hint that the thing being pulled out of the `NSArray` is a pointer to an `NSString`. This stops the compiler complaining about our call to `length`, a method (AKA 'selector') which exists for `NSString` (but not for type `id`).

N.B. Accessing objects in collections, such as NSArray, returns things of type `id`, which is synonymous with `struct objc_object *`,  i.e. a pointer to some object. Hence you will often see type casting on objects that have been removed from arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you take `NSString *myPointer`, this means that you are declaring mypointer as a type of NSString. If you are doing `(NSString *)myPointer`, this means that you are typecasting myPointer to NSString type

Comment: You can perfectly fine declare `int *myPointer`, as a pointer to an integer. And also remember that you can put any data in a pointer to an `NSString`.

Comment: int *mypointer is valid. rest of your answer makes sense. edit that

Comment: @Shanti There is one instance missing, `(NSString *)myPointer` can also appear in a method declaration, you might want to add that to the answer. Ex: `-(void)doSomethingWithString:(NSString *)string;`

Comment: @occulus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Comment: With `NSString *myPointer` you're not declaring `myPointer` "as a type of NSString," you're declaring that myPointer is a pointer to an object of type NSString.

Answer (score 0):

So, heres some things about data types:

Primitive types, such as `unsigned`, `int`, `BOOL`, `double`, `float`, `char`, etc. Do not need to be used with pointers to represent their numerical types, as they represent what you would expect, a number in memory.

When you get into more complex structures, such as classes, as a general rule of thumb, you have `NSObject`, which refers to the `Class` of object, for static method calls (`+new`, `+alloc`, `+initialize`, `+class`, etc.) This type of data structure may not be returned through a method in the format `-(NSObject) myMethodName`, as returning the class object must be done through the class data type, like this: `-(Class) myMethodName`. To get a data type's class, you must call that classes `+class` method, like this: `Class myClass = [NSObject class]` once you have an object's class, you can do interesting things to it, such as send it methods directly to allocate an object, e.g. `NSObject *myObject = [[[NSObject class] alloc] new];`

Now, when you return a pointer to a certain class, e.g. `-(NSObject *) myMethodName`, you return an instance of that class. With that, you have access to the variables of that class, if they are public, such as `Class myClass = [[NSObject alloc] init]->isa`. You can also access instance methods, such as `-init`, `-description`, `-class`, etc. With an instance of a class, you must remember to do your duty and `release` the object when you are done with it, if you have ownership.

Hopefully, this helps. I did not, but can go into detail on `numerical pointers` and `structs`.

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++,
One is pointer to (whatever u use) to (pointer to an array)
and second one is (whatever u use) to pointer (array to pointer).

int *a[10];

Declares and allocates an array of pointers to int.Each element must
be dereferenced individually.

int (*a)[10];

Declares (without allocating) a pointer to an array of int.The
pointer to the array must be dereferenced to access the value of each
element.